# Cheap mobile provider in Denmark

Tags: budget, cellphones, data-plans, denmark

I am visiting Denmark for 4 months. I will need a mobile tariff with data for my Android phone. I won't be making many calls. Does any of the Danish providers offering a prepaid card with large data quota (at least 500 MB/month)? Or will I have to sign a contract?

Comment: I just stumbled upon this post, as I will be studying in Denmark for the next 4 months in a similar situation to both of you. I was just a bit confused about your reply. Did you need to have a Danish social or could you use one from you home country, I am from the US. Thanks!~

Comment: @JordanEdward if you want to sign for a contract, you need a Danish CPR. But you don't really need a contract, you can just get a prepaid card with mobile data.

Answer (score 7):

When you arrive to Denmark and before making any contract with any company just buy SIM card from Lebara from 10 danish kroner it is about 2 us$ that gives you a phone number and a credit for 10 us$, you can buy them from kiosks, 7/11, shop places like Netto, Fakta etc or super markets. You can use it and recharge it, it is not binding, no contract no headache, after while when you are in the country you can research for monthly contract offers and find the reliable solution. Most of monthly contract require Danish ID number (CPR number) and they are binding for minimum of 6 months.

Price gets down every year OR the same price and you get more content in it.

Example CBB offer mobile internet connection from 49,- danish kroner pr month with 1Gb or 89,- danish kroner for 10 hours talk, 10Gb 4G mobile internet.

---

**Update**
Since I posted this answer a lot of things happened, because of hard competitions between telecommunication companies in little Denmark. The company behind CBB and Bibob called Telenor, now has merged both companies and has discounted the old offer of 49,- I mentioned earlier.

So I do not want to make Ad for this or that company but I will write my personal experience and it is always good to be aware of what happening by asking friends, check the internet or ask in forums/community sites like Travel.

Here is a link to comparison table of different telecommunication [companies](http://telepristjek.dk/mobilabonnement-priser) in Denmark the prices might not be up to date, but will give you some estimates and idea where to search.

Regarding [CBB](https://www.cbb.dk/shop/mobilabonnementer/), cheapest offer right now is 69,- that includes 2 hours talk and 1Gb internet connection, but I personally have switch to [Oister](https://www.oister.dk/mobilabonnement/) they have better internet coverage and bandwidth in my location even thus CBB has 4G connection it fill like they have had bad bandwidth in my area. Oister prices starts from 69,- month.

So some time it is not only price but the quality you get and depending on your location. Some companies has better coverage over all in Denmark, some has better in big cities etc. some could have bad coverage in specific locations etc.

My best advice start with non binding SIM cards, and when you fill your self confident, than go a head a try one of the offers, and Remember to ask if they have English contract, otherwise ask some body you know to help you reading the roles and disclaimers before signing in. BTW. most companies offer online ordering of new number, but as I said that required you identification (CPR number) in Denmark.

Finally any one what to know or ask more, you are welcome to comment and I will be glad to come with my knowledge.

---

New update: I have today checked Oister and they have 49,- Kr. offer. that includes 1 hours talking and 1Gb internet [check](https://www.oister.dk/mobilabonnement/taletidsabonnementer/oister-1time/)

**Edit**

Oister charge 10 kr. pr account invoice, if you and have 2 phones number under same account then it is still 10 kr.

Comment: Sir, is the Oister offer binding or not binding? Can a foreign traveler get such a card for 2-weeks temporary use without CPR number but with valid foreign ID (or no id at all)?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible, you are required to have a permanent address, i suggest you Lebara it is ok price and you can charge it on demand

Comment: Thanks for the updates! This is very helpful.  Can you buy an Oister SIM in the same shops Netto, Fakta etc  ?  Also, how do you update it if you want 10 hours talking and 3 GB of data for example?

Comment: They have new product called OiSTER Go, that does not require contract and it should be posibl to buy from diffenet place, I have not try to buy so, I can keep eye and update my comment if I  find so, you can find prices here https://www.oister.dk/go/oister-go-priser/  it starts from 29,- kr and 39,- depending what you need, and you can charge it online on demand.

Answer (score 6):

I am in a very similar situation. I am in Denmark for 5 months on a work visa. I arrived on June 1 and went through the annoying phone search too!

Getting a phone with data is difficult without a contract. The only company that does it is [Telenor](http://www.telenor.dk/) that I could find. Their prices though are about 2-3 times the price of those with a "contract".

To get a "contract" I have had varying replies from suppliers. In general though, they say that you need a CPR number (social security number). I put "contract" in quotes because they said that it is not binding and that I can cancel at anytime without fees. I personally have a 6 month contract with [TDC](http://tdc.dk/). Everything was reasonably easy to sign up and it has worked well with bills every two months. I pay 99 Danish kroner every month for 2 hours talk and 1Gb of data.

I tried figuring this out from home before coming but got no where. Unfortunately you must go to the store and ask questions to get answers. Let me know if you have other questions!

Comment: Were you able to cancel with no fees in the end?

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://www.fullrate.dk/privat/mobil) and [this](https://www.cbb.dk/shop/mobilabonnementer/). So, I think these are the best prices you can get in Denmark with a subscription.

Though, the prices maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ has mentioned for CBB are pretty good. I just cannot find them anywhere.

Comment: Could you please give some details about the two offers you link? Linkis are prone to breaking and once that information is unavailable your answer will be kinda useless. ;)

Comment: Yes, sure.
Fulrate has an offer 119 kr. for either 5 hours of conversation and 25 GB of data or 10 hours of conversation and 20 GB of data.
CBB as an offer of 10 hours of conversation and 20 GB of data for 119 kr.

But I think it could also be interesting if maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ could say where we found those CBB offers or provide a link for it.

Comment: Excellent. Please add this to your answer. If not the information is likely to get lost in the comments.

Comment: check my updated answer hope it helps. cheers

Comment: @JGo now Oister offer the cheap subscription, check my answer update

Comment: If you are only in the country for 4 months, do any of these offers work? That is do they require you pay for 6 months minimum or can you cancel before then with no fees?